# Storing (APN) and (GCM) token in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I want my backend to handle notifications but I am not what data type I should use to store [APN](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) and [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) token in my mysql database.

Right now I am using:

**CHAR 64** for APN

**VARCHAR 250** for GCM

This is just by watching what others have used, but if I understand it right both have a fixed max-length?

Comment: you need to ABC your LMN after maxing out the ZXY

Comment: So, which language are you using? Because you tagged this question with four languages. And what is a "APN" or "GCM"?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Guess I was really tired when I posted this. APN: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html
GCM: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/
I am using Mysql to store the tokens from each service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max size of GCM registration_id is only bounded by the [max size of a cookie](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-c2dm/AUGlvmJPyMM), so it can theoratically be up to 4096 bytes long. In reality the id will be a lot smaller, but you should not rely on it when you design your database.

APNs id is [32 bytes long](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/APNsProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1), but if you want to store the hyphens as well, then make it 36.

Comment: Thank you, so what data type would you recommend me to use in mysql for storing each token?

Comment: This is a design question and I do not know enough about your project, nor wish to learn that much about to answer this question with accuracy. Consult mysql documentation on data types and choose the ones that can store the data and best fit into your application's design: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html